# Benford's Law and ice-cream parlor

Tags: probability

I have a question which might be remotely related to Benford's Law or perhaps the three busses problem (https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn18074-why-three-buses-come-at-once-and-how-to-avoid-it/).
In an ice cream parlor they have the different ice cream flavors in containers which can be half empty, almost empty, completely full, etc. Whenever a container is empty, it is replaced by a new one of the same flavor. The question is: Is it possible to deduce probabilistically which is the customer's favorite flavor based on the amount left in each container?
Can we deduce any valid statistical information with just one snapshot of the state of the containers?

Comment: If they only fill up a container once it is empty and someone wants more, then I'd guess the steady-state distribution over how much is in each container would be uniformly distributed.  However, if they fill up each container in the morning, and only a few people have been by so far, then you could glean more information. Without a fully-specified setup (when are they filled, at what rate and quantity is ice cream bought, etc.) I can't give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is only one reason a container could be almost empty (it's been repeatedly ordered by customers), but two reasons a container could be full, so it's more likely that an almost empty container is more popular than a full one.